# celery force all celery processes to run task

Tags: django, celery

I have a setup with multiple EC2's and I have `celery` running on all of them. I also have one box with `celerybeat` running on it. I'm able to get `celerybeat` to run with tasks running on the remaining `celery` clients.

Is there a way to make a **required** task that *all* `celery` instances have to run? The use case would be clearing logs, running basic sanity checks on the boxes, etc.

I have read the below:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually celery works not as a push-like system, but as a pull-like one.

You just put a task into the queue and one of available workers get it and execute.

From your question I assume that under `instances` you mean `servers` on whose celery's `workers` are running. So you would like to run the same task on all servers.

I think you can only put some tasks (corresponding to servers number) and specify exact routing number for each task (the same as worker's id).

```
mytask.apply_async(kwargs={'a': 1, 'b': 2}, routing_key='aaabbc-dddeeff-243453')
mytask.apply_async(kwargs={'a': 1, 'b': 2}, routing_key='bbbbbb-fffddd-dabcfe')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### [Broadcast](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#broadcast)
>
> Celery can also support broadcast routing. Here is an
>   example exchange broadcast_tasks that delivers copies of tasks to all
>   workers connected to it:
>
> from kombu.common import Broadcast
>
> CELERY_QUEUES = (Broadcast('broadcast_tasks'), )
>
> CELERY_ROUTES = {'tasks.reload_cache': {'queue': 'broadcast_tasks'}}
>   Now the tasks.reload_cache task will be sent to every worker consuming
>   from this queue.